# Play2 elasticsearch error on play dist

Tags: playframework-2.0, elasticsearch

I am using play 2 elastic search plugin (https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch) and in dev mode works ok, but when i run play dist and package the application, after i run it the index is not created.

Here is the stacktrace:

[error] application - ElasticSearch : Error when starting ElasticSearch Client 
org.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchIllegalStateException: Failed to obtain node lock, is the following location writable?: [data/play2-elasticsearch]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.(NodeEnvironment.java:123) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.(InternalNode.java:139) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:166) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar:na]
    at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.IndexClient.start(IndexClient.java:36) ~[com.clever-age.play2-elasticsearch-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.plugin.IndexPlugin.onStart(IndexPlugin.java:47) ~[com.clever-age.play2-elasticsearch-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to obtain lock on /Users/Nicolas/IdeaProjects/lavidaporloscolores/target/universal/stage/data/play2-elasticsearch/nodes/49
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.(NodeEnvironment.java:102) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.(InternalNode.java:139) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:166) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar:na]
    at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.IndexClient.start(IndexClient.java:36) ~[com.clever-age.play2-elasticsearch-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.plugin.IndexPlugin.onStart(IndexPlugin.java:47) ~[com.clever-age.play2-elasticsearch-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory: /Users/Nicolas/IdeaProjects/lavidaporloscolores/target/universal/stage/data/play2-elasticsearch/nodes/49
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.obtain(NativeFSLockFactory.java:171) ~[org.apache.lucene.lucene-core-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0 1504776 - sarowe - 2013-07-19 02:53:42]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.(NodeEnvironment.java:80) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.(InternalNode.java:139) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:166) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar:na]
    at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.IndexClient.start(IndexClient.java:36) ~[com.clever-age.play2-elasticsearch-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT]
[error] application - ElasticSearch : An unexpected exception has occurred during index preparation. Index has not been created and prepared.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.IndexService.existsIndex(IndexService.java:378) ~[com.clever-age.play2-elasticsearch-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.plugin.IndexPlugin.onStart(IndexPlugin.java:58) ~[com.clever-age.play2-elasticsearch-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you add in the question the module configuration that you use ?

Comment: Thanks mguillermin, look at my new post with the answer. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

Add this line on application.conf:

- elasticsearch.config.resource=elasticsearch.yml

Create this file conf/elasticsearch.yml and add

- path.data: /Users/Nicolas/IdeaProjects/lavidaporloscolores/elasticsearchdata

After doing this, i had to run "play dist" again to make play read my new configuration file